# Lifecycle for CGAL vertex handles?

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal, delaunay

I'm a bit confused about the lifecycle of CGAL vertex handles in a Delaunay triangulation. Its not clear to me when the handles are invalidated.

In my application I frequently need to move a single point, and was hoping I could do that without invalidating a structure that holds the vertex handles. (documentation mentions iterators being invalidated)

For example:

1. If a triangulation is rebuilt, are old handles invalidated?
2. If a vertex is removed, what happens to the dangling handle to that vertex?

In this example, a vertex in a triangulation is moved so that it duplicates, which removed the vertex.

```
//https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title42
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel         K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K>                        Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb>                    Tds;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds>                      Delaunay;
typedef Delaunay::Point                                             Point;
int main()
{
    Delaunay T;
    auto handle0 = T.insert(Point(0, 0));
    auto handle1 = T.insert(Point(1, 0));
    auto handle2 = T.insert(Point(1, 1));
    std::cout << "Beginning" << std::endl;
    for (auto v = T.all_vertices_begin(); v != T.all_vertices_end(); ++v)
    {
        std::cout << *v << std::endl;
    }
    T.move(handle2, Point(0, 0));
    std::cout << "Move to invalid will remove the vertex (expected)" << std::endl;
    for (auto v = T.all_vertices_begin(); v != T.all_vertices_end(); ++v)
    {
        std::cout << *v << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Where does this handle point to?" << std::endl;
    T.move(handle2, Point(1, 1));
    std::cout << "Vertices" << std::endl;
    for (auto v = T.all_vertices_begin(); v != T.all_vertices_end(); ++v)
    {
        std::cout << *v << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output

```
Beginning
-9.25596e+61 -9.25596e+61
0 0
1 0
1 1
Move to invalid will remove the vertex (expected)
-9.25596e+61 -9.25596e+61
0 0
1 0
Where does this handle point to?
Vertices
-9.25596e+61 -9.25596e+61
0 0
1 0
```

Comment: For exact details, the documentation is the code. For Vertex_handle, I would expect that it remains valid as long as the vertex exists in the triangulation. When you use an invalidated Vertex_handle, you get undefined behavior, so it may not be that interesting to try and figure out exactly what happens.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Welp. RTFM isn't a very helpful response. For example, in what I posted, `handle0` becomes invalid, despite pointing to a valid vertex.

Comment: I never said RTFM, at most I said that if the manual doesn't have the answer, RTFSource. Do you mean that handle2 (not handle0) becomes invalid? "pointing to a valid vertex" well no, as you said, the vertex was removed, the handle is dangling, you shouldn't use it anymore, `move` returns the new handle you should use instead.

Comment: handle0 is also invalid

Comment: What makes you say that?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Welp, you can never move it back into a useful place.

Answer (score 0):

In CGAL triangulations, iterators and handles are equivalent, and implemented as a pointer.

When a vertex is removed from the triangulation, then one iterator or handle pointing to it is invalidated.

When a vertex is moved, that is equivalent to insert and then remove. The `move` function returns the new (inserted) vertex handle.

In the case of your move, you move one vertex (`handle2`) to the position of an existing one (`handle0`). The insertion will do nothing, and return `handle0`, and the vertex pointed by `handle2` will be removed. And thus `handle2` becomes invalid.